# why transparent drawbox does not work on some video sources?

Tags: ffmpeg

It works on smptebars, smptehdbars, testsrc and testsrc2 but not other sources.

```
ffplay -loglevel trace -f lavfi -i testsrc=r=1:d=1:size=800x600 -vf "drawbox=x=0:y=0:w='iw/2':h='ih/2':t=max:c=white@0.5"
```

When I try this I can see the transparent box. But if I use color, and rgbtestsrc sources it does not work.

```
ffplay -loglevel trace -f lavfi -i rgbtestsrc=r=1:d=1:size=800x600 -vf "drawbox=x=0:y=0:w='iw/2':h='ih/2':t=max:c=white@0.5"
ffplay -loglevel trace -f lavfi -i color=c=red:r=1:d=1:size=800x600 -vf "drawbox=x=0:y=0:w='iw/2':h='ih/2':t=max:c=white@0.5"
```

after looking at the trace output, it seems the transparency only works on rgb24 and yuv formats (yuv444p, yuv420p, etc.), this is surprising since we normally assume the rgba source can work with alpha channel.

The following command change the pix_fmt to rgb24, then it works:

```
ffplay -loglevel trace -f lavfi -i rgbtestsrc=r=1:d=1:size=800x600 -vf "format=pix_fmts=rgb24,drawbox=x=0:y=0:w='iw/2':h='ih/2':t=max:c=white@0.5"
```

The following command change the pix_fmt to rgba, then it does not work:

```
ffplay -loglevel trace -f lavfi -i rgbtestsrc=r=1:d=1:size=800x600 -vf "format=pix_fmts=rgba,drawbox=x=0:y=0:w='iw/2':h='ih/2':t=max:c=white@0.5"
```

Why is that? and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce here. You're using an old build of ffmpeg. There was a bug in drawbox to do with transparency, but it was fixed in Dec 2017.

Comment: I am on 3.4.6 I guess the bug is still affect this version. I will try on 4.x then.